# Оптимизировать многократную инициализацию класса

Tags: php

Данный код 2 раза инициализирует курл и закроет его, моя цель - запустить курл один раз, а затем делать несколько запросов curl_exec.

```
//config.php
$c = [
    0 => class1::class,
    1 => class2::class
];

//класс курла
class Curl
{
    protected $ch;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    function request($method, $url, $options = [])
    {
        return 'parsed';
    }


    function init()
    {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
        var_dump('init');
    }


    function __destruct()
    {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
}

//класс ответа сервера
class Response
{
    function get()
    {
        global $c;
        $arr = [];

        foreach ($c as $item) {
            $super = new $item();
            /**
             * @var Superclass $super
             */
            $arr[] = $super->request();
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}

//класс родительский
class Superclass
{
    //общий функционал
    function request()
    {
        $c = new Curl();
        return $c->request('GET', 'http://ya.ru');
    }
}

//дочерние
class class1 extends Superclass
{
    //реализация метода request отличается от class2
}

class class2 extends Superclass
{
    //реализация метода request отличается от class1
}

//контроллер
$r = new Response();
var_dump($r->get());
```

Первое, что приходит на ум - вынести `$c = new Curl()` в самый верх, например в Response, там где цикл foreach, то тогда придется передавать $c параметром в конструктор class1/class2.

Может есть более оптимизированный вариант? Через статику?

Comment: Синглтон? Или реестр для хранения созданных объектов.

Comment: Это классический пример ситуации, для которой синглтон является одним из лучших решений (и не слушайте хейтеров, которые называют его антипаттерном - они просто не умеют его готовить :)

Comment: @Visman спасибо за пинок, вроде разобрался.

Comment: @rjhdby да, все хорошо, черканул.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, сваял такое:

```
echo Singleton::getInstance()->url('http://php.net')->exec();
echo Singleton::getInstance()->url('https://ya.ru')->exec();

final class Singleton
{
    /**
     * @var Singleton
     */
    private static $instance = null;
    private $ch = null;

    /**
     * @return Singleton
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->ch)) {
            $this->ch = curl_init();
            var_dump('curl_init()');
        }
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 30);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    }

    public function exec()
    {
        $exec = curl_exec($this->ch);
        return mb_strlen($exec) . ' ';
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (!is_null(static::$instance)) {
            curl_close($this->ch);
            var_dump('curl_close()');
        }
    }

    public function url($url)
    {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        return static::$instance;
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }
}
```

Выведет

```
string 'curl_init()' (length=11)

10365 68121

string 'curl_close()' (length=12)
```

Правда какие-то ошибки повылазили в дебагере, и $instance рекурсивно ссылается сама на себя (это, я так понял, так и должно быть в следствии ссылания само на себя).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. `ch` - НЕ static. Прочитайте, что такое синглтон. В нем статичен только экземпляр класса, ничего более. 2. Расставьте методам модификаторы доступа -это хороший тон

Comment: @rjhdby подправил, но пришлось убрать getInstance($url), так как при втором обращении к Singleton::getInstance() не срабатывает конструктор, в котором я устанавливал CURLOPT_URL. В модификаторах доступа у меня нет острой нужды в этом тестовом коде, скопировано с гитхаба..

Comment: Правильно ли понимаю, что это в основном нужно ради keep-alive? Если указывать cURL разные хосты в адресе, то он с инкапсулированными в себе сокетами сам разберется? Есть ли тогда возможность, например, закрыть keep-alive соединение с одним хостом, а с другими оставить?

Answer (score 1):

Так как PHP по сути своей однопоточный(экзотику не рассматриваем), то синглтон для него очень простой:

```
class Datasource{
    private $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(selsf::$instanse == null){
            self::$instance = new Datasource();
        }
        return self::$instanse;
    }

    public function doSomeStuff( ...

    ... 
}
```

Этот шаблон проектирования идеально подходит для соединений с БД и прочих ресурсов, соединение и позиционирование внутри которых должны быть едиными для всего кода.

Также имеет место быть более наивная реализация? если вам не нужна обвязка пользовательских методов

```
class Datasource{
    private $connection;

    public static function getConnection(){
        if(self::$connection === null){
            self::$connection = new SomeClass();
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
}
```